# I get the error " print("Connected to %s on port %s" % (address, port)) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python

```
import socket
import re
import sys
import logging
from __future__ import print_function
def check_server(address, port):
    #Create a TCP Socket
    s = socket.socket()
    print("Attempting to connect to %s on port %s" % (address, port))
    try:    
        s.connect((address, port)
        print("Connected to %s on port %s" % (address, port))
        return True
    except socket.error, e;
        print("Connection to %s on port %s failed: %s" % (address, port, e))
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from optparse import OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser()

    parser.add_option("-a", "--address", dest="address", default='localhost', help="ADDRESS for server", metavar="ADDRESS")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--port", dest="port", type="int", default=10001, help="PORT for server", metavar="PORT")

    (options, arg) = parser.parse_args()
    print 'options: %s, args: %s' % (options, args)
    check = check_server(options.address, options.port)
    print 'check_server returned %s' % check

    sys.exit(not check)
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Because `from __future__ import print_function`, I think OP is using Python 2.

Comment: @KevinGuan Well well, `__future__` statements should be placed at the top then, no wonder I missed it.

Comment: To start with the [`future` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements) should be at the top of the file. Another error: `e;` should be `e:`, or even better use `as e:`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary http://pastebin.com/vCCEsEZv <------ is that better. it still gives me these errors:                                                                           options: {'port': 10001, 'address': 'localhost'}, args: []
Attempting to connect to localhost on port 10001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Port-checker.py", line 28, in <module>
    check = check_server(options.address, options.port)
  File "Port-checker.py", line 12, in check_server
    s.connect(address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str

Comment: @KrazyBakon `s.connect(address, port)` should be `s.connect((address, port))`.

Comment: i still get ******* errors. options: {'port': 10001, 'address': 'localhost'}, args: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Port-checker.py", line 29, in <module>
    check = check_server(options.address, options.port)
TypeError: check_server() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @KrazyBakon Read the error message couple of times(it is pretty much plain English) and figure it out. ;-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i get the 2 argument's given but i dont know a workaround

Answer (score 1):

replace the following code

```
    try:    
        s.connect((address, port)
        print("Connected to %s on port %s" % (address, port))
        return True
    except socket.error, e;
        print("Connection to %s on port %s failed: %s" % (address, port, e))
        return False
```

with

```
    try:    
        s.connect((address, port))
        print("Connected to %s on port %s" % (address, port))
        return True
    except socket.error, e;
        print("Connection to %s on port %s failed: %s" % (address, port, e))
        return False
```

Comment: More details:  OP forgot close a `(` here: `s.connect((address, port)`.